# Incorrect row index when grouping

Tags: mysql

I have built the following query:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.tag_id,
    p.title,
    p.created_at,
    @indexer := @indexer + 1 AS indexer
FROM 
    `posts` AS p
LEFT JOIN
    `votes` AS v
        ON p.id = v.votable_id
        AND v.votable_type = "Post"
        AND v.deleted_at IS NULL
JOIN
    (SELECT @indexer := 0) AS i
WHERE
    p.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY
    p.id
```

The result I am getting with this is:

```
+----+--------+------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| id | tag_id |               title                |     created_at      | indexer |
+----+--------+------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
|  2 |      2 | PostPostPost                       | 2014-10-23 23:53:15 |     248 |
|  3 |      3 | Title                              | 2014-10-23 23:56:13 |       6 |
|  4 |      2 | GIFGIFIGIIF                        | 2014-10-23 23:59:03 |    1316 |
|  5 |      2 | GIFGIFIGIIF                        | 2014-10-23 23:59:03 |    1317 |
|  6 |      4 | My new avatar                      | 2014-10-26 22:22:30 |    1318 |
|  7 |      5 | Hi, haiii, oh Hey !                | 2014-10-26 22:38:10 |       1 |
|  8 |      6 | Mclaren testing stealth technology | 2014-10-26 22:44:15 |       5 |
|  9 |      7 | Just random thoughts while pooping | 2014-10-26 22:50:03 |       2 |
+----+--------+------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Yet, I am expecting this:

```
+----+--------+------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| id | tag_id |               title                |     created_at      | indexer |
+----+--------+------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
|  2 |      2 | PostPostPost                       | 2014-10-23 23:53:15 |       1 |
|  3 |      3 | Title                              | 2014-10-23 23:56:13 |       2 |
|  4 |      2 | GIFGIFIGIIF                        | 2014-10-23 23:59:03 |       3 |
|  5 |      2 | GIFGIFIGIIF                        | 2014-10-23 23:59:03 |       4 |
|  6 |      4 | My new avatar                      | 2014-10-26 22:22:30 |       5 |
|  7 |      5 | Hi, haiii, oh Hey !                | 2014-10-26 22:38:10 |       6 |
|  8 |      6 | Mclaren testing stealth technology | 2014-10-26 22:44:15 |       7 |
|  9 |      7 | Just random thoughts while pooping | 2014-10-26 22:50:03 |       8 |
+----+--------+------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

*Hint:* The problem is with `indexer` field. It happened after adding the `GROUP BY` statement.

I have tried moving the `JOIN (SELECT @indexer := 0) AS i` around, changing it to simply an extra select, but no changes. The indices are screwed up anyways.

How do I fix this, so that the indexes are correct?
And what is the reasoning behind this problem?

Comment: it has to do with when mysql evaluates the `@i := @i + 1`. it's occuring at a different time in the execution sequence than you're expecting, and giving you these wonky numbers. it is properly calculating `i++`, but mosf of the results rows are dropped by your join and/or where, causing the "gaps" in the seqeuence. there aren't really any gaps, but rows are being dropped producing the illusion of gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself, had to separate the query into multiple subqueries.

```
SELECT
    mq.*,
    @indexer := @indexer + 1 AS indexer
FROM
(
    SELECT
        p.id,
        p.tag_id,
        p.title,
        p.created_at
    FROM 
        `posts` AS p
    LEFT JOIN
        `votes` AS v
            ON p.id = v.votable_id
            AND v.votable_type = "Post"
            AND v.deleted_at IS NULL
    WHERE
        p.deleted_at IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        p.id
) AS mq
JOIN
    (SELECT @indexer := 0) AS i
```

Apparently, that caused huge amount of accessed rows for the query (as per `EXPLAIN`), but managed to fix that too with extra indices. The full answer to that problem can be found here: [Calculating row indices with subquery having joins, results in A*B examined rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098454/calculating-row-indices-with-subquery-having-joins-results-in-ab-examined-rows)