# Calculating row indices with subquery having joins, results in A*B examined rows

Tags: mysql

This question is derived from a one I started previously: [Incorrect row index when grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095974/incorrect-row-index-when-grouping)

Due to different natures, I'm asking here and will provide the answer back there once I have resolved *this* issue.

---

I thought about subqueries, and came up with this:

```
SELECT
    mq.*,
    @indexer := @indexer + 1 AS indexer
FROM
(
    SELECT
        p.id,
        p.tag_id,
        p.title,
        p.created_at
    FROM 
        `posts` AS p
    LEFT JOIN
        `votes` AS v
            ON p.id = v.votable_id
            AND v.votable_type = "Post"
            AND v.deleted_at IS NULL
    WHERE
        p.deleted_at IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        p.id
) AS mq
JOIN
    (SELECT @indexer := 0) AS i
```

Which actually works, I get the desired result:

```
+----+--------+------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
| id | tag_id |               title                |     created_at      | indexer |
+----+--------+------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
|  2 |      2 | PostPostPost                       | 2014-10-23 23:53:15 |       1 |
|  3 |      3 | Title                              | 2014-10-23 23:56:13 |       2 |
|  4 |      2 | GIFGIFIGIIF                        | 2014-10-23 23:59:03 |       3 |
|  5 |      2 | GIFGIFIGIIF                        | 2014-10-23 23:59:03 |       4 |
|  6 |      4 | My new avatar                      | 2014-10-26 22:22:30 |       5 |
|  7 |      5 | Hi, haiii, oh Hey !                | 2014-10-26 22:38:10 |       6 |
|  8 |      6 | Mclaren testing stealth technology | 2014-10-26 22:44:15 |       7 |
|  9 |      7 | Just random thoughts while pooping | 2014-10-26 22:50:03 |       8 |
+----+--------+------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

The problem now is... I ran a `EXPLAIN` query, to see how fast it works. And, I have a number there that is really bugging me:

[image: Abnormally high row count.]

Well, the number is obvious: `252 * 1663 = 419076`.

This worries me, though - is the row count normal there, or I have to optimize the query? And if so, then how do I optimize this one?

Comment: how do your indizes look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of MySQL [version 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) all joins are treated as nested loop joins.

> MySQL resolves all joins using a nested-loop join method. This means that MySQL reads a row from the first table, and then finds a matching row in the second table, the third table, and so on.

So to answer your question... no, you won't be able to get that row count down.  However, by adding indexes to your join columns you may be able to achieve faster results but your row count will be the same.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Yeah, I added indices - it did reduce the row count significantly, but it still remains `A*B`, though, it's at 745 now, not tens of thousands.